# Python Class Method: object has no attribute + object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class elem:
    def __init__(self, coords):
        if not coords.shape == (2, 3):
            raise TypeError("")
    def Jac(self, f):
        x1, x2, x3 = self[0,:]
        y1, y2, y3 = self[1,:]
        A = array([[x2 - x1, x3 - x1],
                   [y2 - y1, y3 - y1]])
        J = det(A)
    def f_(xi, eta):
        x = x1 + (x2 - x1)*xi + (x3 - x1)*eta
        y = y1 + (y2 - y1)*xi + (y3 - y1)*eta
        return f(x, y)
    return (1/6)(f_(0, 0) + f_(0, 1) + f_(1, 0))

def f(x, y):
    return x**2/10 - y**2/10 + 1

el = array([[3, 11, 0],
            [0, 4, 6]])
EL = elem(el)
print(EL.Jac(f))
```

When I ran this code, there was a TypeError: 'elem' object is not subscriptable.
If I substitute

```
x1, x2, x3 = self[0,:]
```

with

```
x1, x2, x3 = self.coords[0,:]
```

it would raise AttributeError: 'elem' object has no attribute 'coords'.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Yes, those error messages are telling you exactly what the problem is. Your `elem` class does not support indexing, i.e. `some_object[<whatever>]` is indexing, and you don't have a `coords` attribute either. You likely meant to do `self.coords = cords` in `__init__`

Comment: Solved perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## `__getitem__`

In order for an object to be substricptable, you need to implement **getitem** ([https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**getitem**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)) in the class.

However you need to assign the value to the object, for example

```
class Some:

    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.v[i]


some = Some([1,2,3])
print(some[:2])
```

results in

```
[1, 2]
```

This should work with numpy as well, which I assume you use.

### `collections.UserList`

Basically, what you want, is to extend the lists functionality. You can use the UserList class from the build in collections module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList

However, this does not work with numpy arrays, as far as I know.

### `numpy.ndarray`

In numpy you can inherit from the ndarray class, for example:

```
from numpy import ndarray


class A(ndarray):    
    def custom_function(self, x):
        return self + x

a = A([1,2,3])
print(a.custom_function(666))
```

results in

```
A([[[666., 666., 666.],
    [666., 666., 666.]]])
```

Links:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#basics-subclassing
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy.ndarray

*Both examples are subscriptable.*

I hope this helps.

#### Some more

Your code won't work, because you have a return statement in the class body, instead of a function.

Please, do not forget to state import statements in questions. array is not part of the python standard library. I just guess it is numpy, because of the shape property.